# How to pass a custom model manager queryset to a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I am trying to pass a custom query to a template but the query results are not being displayed.

I had a working solution for this but I wanted to implement a custom model manager to simplify the code but I cant get the final step work - that is displaying the results on the template

I have a custom manager:

```
from django.db import models


class ProfileQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_users_follows(self, user):
        print(user)
        return self.filter(followed_by__user__username=user)


class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProfileQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def get_users_follows(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().get_users_follows(user)
```

which is instantiated in the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)
    objects = ProfileManager()
```

my view is as follows:

```
class FollowsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    # Follow.follow_data = [[],[]]
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'blog/follows.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    # paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        follow_data = Profile.objects.get_users_follows(self.request.user)
        context = {'follow_data', follow_data}
        return context
```

In the template i am calling the follow_data like so:

```
{{ follow_data }}
    {% for p in follow_data %}
    {% if p.user %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ p.user.profile.image.url }}" alt="">
        <a href="{% url 'user-posts' p.user %}">{{ p.user.profile.user }}</a>
    {% else %}
      <p>You are not following any users</p>
    {% endif %}

    </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

but no results are being displayed so I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone provide me weith a quick pointer on what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
context = {'follow_data', follow_data}
```

You've created a set, but what you really want is a dict

```
context = {'follow_data': follow_data}
```

edit:

but you shouldn't be returning a context here anyway, you should return a queryset. simply do `return follow_data` should work.

in your template, you can refer to the queryset with `{% for user in object_list %}`

If you don't want to call it "object_list" you'll need to override `get_context_data`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["follow_data"] = context.pop("object_list")
    return context
```

doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: Hi there. I tried ```follow_data = Profile.objects.get_users_follows(self.request.user) return follow_data``` but that didnt seem to work in the template

Comment: u need to use `{% for user in object_list %}` as that's what it's called in the default context. to rename it to `follow_data` you need to also implement the `get_context_data` shown in the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! Seems to work now. I just removed the get_context_data...works ok

Comment: Hi rabbit one last question how do you return 2 query sets in the same ListView?

Comment: I guess in this case there is really no benefit of using ListView, simply write your own view class that extends `django.views.TemplateView` and write your own `get_context_data` to return relevant context.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView